# Purchasing an iMac but pay every month

Tags: hardware-recommendation, apple-inc

I'm not sure about this, but I just want to know if it's possible to purchase a product from the Apple website, but not to pay in full, but pay every month since I cannot fully pay the whole price of a 27" iMac but I can if I pay every month.

Cheers.

---

**EDIT:**

Ok, I had a chat with an Apple Expert on the live chat (via the website) in order to pay monthly, you will have to place an order WITH a financial payment which is label in the payment method (second tab on the panel).

After that, confirm your order and you will be redirected to an Apple "Apply Now" which you will place an confirmation for Apple to approve or disapprove, if you are approved you will be sent an application - if you dislike the Terms and Conditions, your order will be canceled.

---

Cheers guys, hope this will help everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple offers financing for a lot of their products. Typically you will see a link above the "Select" button for a given product on its page. See the image below from the Mac Mini catalog page...

[image: "financing available"]

The financing may not come from Apple directly, but it is an option.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are in the UK, this financing option is available from Apple, if it is a business purchase you can also lease Apple hardware.

However, depending on how long you want to spread the payments over you can look for an interest free offer on a credit card, usually up to 12 months so you can make a big purchase then have 12 months to pay it off, as long as you make the minimum payment each month you don't pay anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is reasonable to look through refurbished products https://tech.trade/ . Their price is not so high, that's why it can become good alternative

Answer (score -5):

As far as I know, Apple don't offer any hire purchase or leasing arrangements through the Apple store or website. You will need to find a third party to lend you the money.